# Max field set size exceeded in Spartacus set-up

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, storefront, commerce

I'm adding a new field to the ProductWSDTO and making the necessary additions to use this field on the spartacus frontend. But when I want to open PDP, I get the following error. How can I solve this problem?

de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.ConversionException: Max field set size exceeded. Reason of that can be : too generic configuration, lack of properly defined BASIC field set level for data class, reccurency in data structure

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP8] [RestHandlerExceptionResolver] de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.ConversionException: Max field set size exceeded. Reason of that can be : too generic configuration, lack of properly defined BASIC field set level for data class, reccurency in data structure
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.addToFieldSet(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:536)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:522)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:217)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetForLevel(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:286)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:211)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:517)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseParametrizedTypeField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:452)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:319)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:217)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetForLevel(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:286)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:211)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:517)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseParametrizedTypeField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:452)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:319)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:217)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetForLevel(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:286)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:211)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:517)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseParametrizedTypeField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:452)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:319)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:217)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetForLevel(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:286)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:211)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:517)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseParametrizedTypeField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:452)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:319)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:217)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetForLevel(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:286)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.createFieldSetInternal(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:211)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:517)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:331)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseParametrizedTypeField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:452)
at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder.parseComplexField(DefaultFieldSetBuilder.java:319)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add field-level mapping for the new attribute.

Comment: You have have an attribute which has deep levels or recursion. It could possibly be related to product data or category data. You will need to refine the fields you are returning. As of this time, it's simply too big.

Answer (score 1):

@Rebia,

Below are the steps to avoid the above issue.

1.define a field mapper to fill up the new field in ProductWsDTO

[image]

2. added new field in fieldSetLevelMapping:

entry key="BASIC" value="totalPageCount,catalog,totalProductCount,currentPage,products,version,myProperty"

3. Inject right populator to populate value in WSDTO.
4. It seems your DTO is too complex so do changes in this file.
   dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml
   [image]

Here try to change defaultMaxFieldSetSize to 80k

Comment: Hello @Raushan,Thank you for your answer, I implemented the solution but the error still persists.

Comment: Hello @Raushan,Thank you for your answer, I implemented the solution but the error still persists.

Comment: Please share all steps and file changes then it would be easy to understand the problem

Comment: Hello @Raushan, 1) xxxfacades-beans.xml add new property , 2) xxxocc-beans.xml add new property , 3) xxxocc-web-spring.xml add new property, 4)app.module.ts add new property , 5) I also did the setting of the Populator class.

Comment: And I added this as you said :  <bean parent="fieldMapper">
  <property name="sourceClass" value="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData"/>
  <property name="destClass" value="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.product.ProductWsDTO"/>
  <property name="fieldMapping">
   <map>
    <entry key="customerFavouriteList" value="customerFavouriteList"/>
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: @Rabia Did you find any fix? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to handling 'fields' parameter :

- https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c404c5886691014a48c88f4a49f9bf3.html
- Section 'Fields configuration', 'Field Set Builder' : https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/e571a0e6f7524d4ab62e29cc2b387aeb.html

Mapping mechanism in occ is based on Orika mapper.
There is additional filter which check if currently mapped attribute is on the list of attributes which should be mapped. That list is created based on class definition and fieldSetLevelMappings by fieldSetBuilder (defined in dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml)

```
 <alias alias="fieldSetBuilder" name="defaultFieldSetBuilder"/>
     <bean id="defaultFieldSetBuilder"
           class="de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultFieldSetBuilder">
         <property name="defaultRecurrencyLevel" value="4"/>
         <property name="defaultMaxFieldSetSize" value="50000"/>
         <property name="fieldSetLevelHelper" ref="fieldSetLevelHelper"/>
     </bean>
```

There are two parameters which can influence how the field set builder works :

- defaultRecurrencyLevel
- defaultMaxFieldSetSize - If the limit is exceeded, an exception is thrown - this is exception you see.
  It looks like for request you try to do - response dto is too complex
  Verify if fieldsSetMapping for that dto class was defined properly.

If you don't specify any fields attribute in request - value is taken from DEFAULT fieldSetLevelMapping.
Try to specify fields attribute for your call and verify if you still get that exception.

Check this [thread](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12768955/issue-in-occ-data-mapper.html) in SAP community for detail.

Best Regards,
Jerry